# Sort according to second column numerically and first alphabetically

Tags: bash, sorting

I have 2 columns, I want to sort them using bash.

I used the command:

```
sort -k2 -n
c 9
c 11
c 11
sh 11
c 13
c 15
txt 47
txt 94
txt 345
txt 628
sh 3673
```

This is the result, but i need them to be sorted like this:

```
c 9
c 11
c 11
c 13
c 15
sh 11
sh 3673
txt 47
txt 94
txt 345
txt 628
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First `sort` by column 1, then by 2:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n file.txt
```

Comment: Ty very much. :D Thought i had to use sed or awk for it.

Comment: @Holajz Glad i could help :)